# prestashop fixed menu after scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, php, css, prestashop, z-index

I have fixed top menu and titlecart dropdown menu issue. When I am on my website before I scroll it down titlecart have correctly dropdown, please check picture below[image]

but when I scroll down and my fixed menu stick to the top and I want to come back and check a cart again title cart look like this:
[image]

search form cover titlecart drop down, I know that there is a problem with Z-Index, I tried to find solution everywhere and couldn't find any results. If someone had simmilar issue and know what to do let me know please.

For more information I will add [my website](http://wrzosowybutik.com/)

Please let me know if something more is needed to check the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a higher z-index to your header-container element I found that     z-index of 10000 works in your case.

```
.header-container {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

**Update**

As sarcom suggested in the comments, you need to manage the z-indexes in your website so they don't get out of hand and you don't run into similar problems.

Here is a good article on the topic of z-index management: https://medium.com/science-journal/z-index-organization-in-css-5913fd4c25c9

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Before that I tried evertyhing :). Thank you

Comment: The z-index isn't a simple value to increment at infinity, it needs a correct management...

Comment: Good improvement of the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that there is something like organization of z-index, good article.

Answer (score 2):

Fix:
global.css

```
# 5552 z-index: 0;
```

Fix: 
blockcart.css

```
# 136 z-index: 1031;
```

Comment: Oh yes, I know :)